# "Undefined" Error in discord.js, can somebody help me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I started making an RPG Game in Discord with `discord.js`, but I got an error. Here is my code and the error:

```
let exp = require("./exp.json");
let userEXP = exp[message.author.id].exp;

if (voidCost) {
    exp[message.author.id] = {
        exp: exp[message.author.id].exp - 1700
    }

    fs.writeFile("./exp.json", JSON.stringify(exp), (err) => {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err)
        }
    })
}

let Void = require(`./weapons/Void.json`);

if (voidAmt) {
    Void[message.author.id] = {
        Void: Void[message.author.id].Void + 3
    }

    fs.writeFile("./weapons/Void.json", JSON.stringify(Void), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}

if (!Void[message.author.id]) {
    Void[message.author.id] = {
        Void: 0
    }
}
```

The error:

```
(node:8632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
Cannot read property 'Void' of undefined` (referred to "Void[message.author.id].Void")
```

Can somebody help me? What does the error mean and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I do not know `discord.js` but it tells you that `Void[message.author.id]` is undefined (meaning that the object is not defined and you cannot access its properties). You are trying to call the method `Void` from an undefined object.

Comment: As far as I can see, the error happens in this line: `Void: Void[message.author.id].Void + 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
let Void = require(`./weapons/Void.json`);

if (voidAmt) {
    if (!Void[message.author.id]) {
        Void[message.author.id] = {
            Void: 0
        }
    }

    Void[message.author.id] = {
        Void: Void[message.author.id].Void + 3
    }

    fs.writeFile("./weapons/Void.json", JSON.stringify(Void), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}
```

So basically just move the check up.

Just saying using JSON for a Database is not very reliable and may corrupt your data.
A good alternative would be https://www.npmjs.com/package/enmap, wich is atleast somewhat failsave and has easier useabilitty